# How to encrypt a file with private key

Tags: openssl, gpg, signature

I want to encrypt a file with a private key and decrypt it with a public key. A public key will be embedded in my app. So I want to have a guarantee that the file was created by me. How can I use gpg or openssl to implement it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295786/can-one-encrypt-with-a-private-key-decrypt-with-a-public-key http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86595/why-cant-you-work-backwards-with-public-key-to-decrypt-a-message

Comment: What you're describing sounds like signing (making sure the file was created by somebody who knows the private key), not encrypting (making sure only somebody with the private key can read it)?

Comment: PHP also has a function for encrypting with a private key. I have not used it myself, but did want to share it here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It makes no sense to encrypt a file with a private key](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59675/can-a-public-key-be-used-to-decrypt-a-message-encrypted-by-the-corresponding-pri).

Using a private key to attach a tag to a file that guarantees that the file was provided by the holder of the private key is called **[signing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)**, and the tag is called a **signature**.

There is one popular cryptosystem (textbook RSA) where a simplified (insecure) algorithm uses has public and private keys of the same type, and decryption is identical to signature and encryption is identical to verification. This is not the case in general: even RSA uses different mechanisms for decryption and signature (resp. encryption and verification) with proper, secure padding modes; and many other algorithms have private and public keys that aren't even the same kind of mathematical objects.

So you want to sign the file. The de facto standard tool for this is [GnuPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuPG).

To sign a file with your secret key:

```
gpg -s /path/to/file
```

Use the `--local-user` option to select a secret key if you have several (e.g. your app key vs your personal key).

Transfer `file.gpg` to the place where you want to use the file. Transfer the public key as well (presumably inside the application bundle). To extract the original text and verify the signature, run

```
gpg file.gpg
```

If it's more convenient, you can transfer `file` itself, and produce a separate signature file which is called a detached signature. To produce the detached signature:

```
gpg -b /path/to/file
```

To verify:

```
gpg file.gpg file
```

You can additionally encrypt the file with the `-e` option. Of course this means that you need a separate key pair, where the recipient (specified with the `-r` option) has the private key and the producer has the public key.

Comment: _It makes no sense..._ Disagree. Consider deployment of a secure package to multiple endpoints from a _guaranteed_ single source. The encrypted package provides both content security and, intrinsically, the signature.  Alternately, the package is encrypted with a symmetric key which is protected asymmetrically then bundled together for delivery. A wholly, asymmetrically encrypted package is preferable -- even if not possible today.

Comment: @bvj Then you aren't encrypting with a private key, as in, the private part of a key pair for an asymmetric cryptographic scheme. You're encrypting with a *secret key*. (Terminology isn't completely standardized, but most of the world uses “private key” only in the context of public-key cryptography, and uses “secret key” in the context of symmetric cryptography.) With public-key cryptography, if you're using a private key, you're either decrypting or signing, not encrypting.

Comment: Thanks, @Gilles. Notwithstanding convention, isn't it possible via RSA to encrypt with the _private_ key and subsequently decrypt with only the _public_ key? The endpoints I referred to would be securely configured with the _public_ key. Thereafter, they'd receive payloads that could certainly be signed with the sender's _private_ key, but preferably receive an additional symmetric key encrypted by the sender's _private_ key. The symmetric key could then decrypt the protected payload. Signing is essential, obscurity is preferable. The endpoints could be IoTs for example.

Comment: @bvj No: you encrypt the symmetric key with the recipient's public key. Even if you could encrypt with the sender's private key, anybody could decrypt it with the corresponding public key, so that would make the encryption pointless. Encrypting with a private key, or signing with a public key, is technically possible with RSA (but typically not with other public-key algorithms, as in, you can perform the mathematical operation, but it doesn't have any interesting security property.

Comment: So basically two sets of key pairs are required where both the sender and recipient each have their own private key. Thank you, Gilles!

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I does make provide an interesting security property. If provides authentication of who the sender is, as well it makes data decipherable by only those you have provided a the public key counter part to. This use case is documented in Chapter 2 of Computer Security, 2019, by Starlings and Brown.

Comment: @AndrewS “provides authentication of who the sender is, as well it makes data decipherable by only those you have provided a the public key” you can get this with AEAD (symmetric-key authentication+encryption), but it's not a direct property of any widespread basic asymmetric cryptosystem, in particular it isn't something you can do with RSA as commonly implemented. I'm not sure if it's achievable with a modified RSA where the public exponent is random and private. The difficulty is making sure that neither exponent can be reconstructed.

Comment: @AndrewS The standard way of achieving both asymmetric authentication and asymmetric encryption is to do the two separately: with two RSA key pairs (RSA-PSS + RSA-OAEP), or with two ECC key pairs (ECDSA + ECIES).

Comment: @Giles-'SO Thanks for the the suggestion about the other way of achieving this.  This has got me thinking, I wonder how many other prominent text books on networking or computer security make this point because I'm sure I've seen this before in other places too. I'm going to spend some time in the library. I have pulled up the original 1976 paper by, W. Diffie and M. Helman, as well as another one by  R.Rivest, A. Shamir, L. Alderman from 1978. I'm not doubting your opinion here and in other posts, but I do want to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 10):

Use OpenSSL to do that. Follow a simple example:

To encrypt a file:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -in <decrypted file> -out <encrypted file>
```

To decrypt a file:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private_key.pem -in <encrypted file> -out <decrypted file>
```

Comment: He is asking how to encrypt using Private Key.

Answer (score 8):

You can encrypt with a private key and decrypt with its public key:

- To encrypt

  ```
  $ TEXT="proof that private key can encrypt and public key can decrypt"
  $ echo "$TEXT" | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey private.key -in - -out - | base64 > encrypted.txt
  ```
- To decrypt

  ```
  $ cat encrypted.txt | base64 -d | openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey public.key -in -
  proof that private key can encrypt and public key can decrypt
  ```

As you can see, the decrypted file correctly matches the text we wrote into it in the encryption step.

Comment: This is the right answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: As explained in other answers, signing is NOT the same as encryption.  For one thing, a signature is a fixed length.  Your example 61 bytes only works because it is a very small piece of data you are using.  Try making your text longer and it will fail with: data too large for key size

Comment: This won't work at all. `stdin is not a tty`

Answer (score 0):

You're speaking of an app. That means you probably want to use a library, not a command line. How to do that is out of scope for UNIX & Linux SE (and you didn't even tell us what language your app is written in), but there are several libraries which can do what you want:

- OpenSSL's [libcrypto](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/) has several primitives to deal with signature verification
- [GPGME](https://www.gnupg.org/(es)/related_software/gpgme/index.html) is a library written by the author's of GnuPG, which allows many things, among them signature verification.
- GnuTLS also exposes its internal [cryptographic primitives](http://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Using-GnuTLS-as-a-cryptographic-library.html), however they don't recommend it.

I'm sure there are more, these are just the most popular solutions. Most of these libraries have bindings for other languages, too, in case you're not using C.

Answer (score 0):

As @rsmoorthy 's, you can encrypt a sentence or a tiny file, which MUST be shorter than the key. To encrypt a larger file you should use rsa along with aes.

```
# Assuming you're using linux
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid | sed 's/-//g' | tee key.plain
$ openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -in test.zip -out test.zip.enc -k $(cat key.plain)
# Assuming you have a pair of rsa keys (crypt.priv and crypt.pub)
$ openssl rsautl -sign -inkey crypt.priv -in key.plain -out key.enc
```

Now decrypt the file with 'test.zip.enc', 'crypt.pub' and 'key.enc':

```
$ openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey crypt.pub -in key.enc -out key.de
$ openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in test.zip.enc -out de.zip -k $(cat key.de)
```